# How to ignore (or convert) "\N" in a CSV with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a very large CSV file with many cells that have "\N" as the value. For example:

| OBJ_1 | OBJ_2 | TCA |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 16908 | 37152 | 2019-07-29 01:13:37 |
| 37152 | 16908 | 2019-07-29 01:13:37 |
| 16908 | 37152 | 2019-07-29 01:13:37 |
| \N | 16908 | 2019-07-29 01:13:37 |
| 19483 | 23132 | \N |
| 22829 | \N | 2019-07-29 01:13:37 |

When I run the function to read the file: `pd.read_csv("path")`

I get the error: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: '\\N'`

How can I read a CSV file with "\N" values and have them either ignored or replaced with some default value (like zero or undefined)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), you can use the `na_values` argument to automatically convert these to NaNs, like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv("path", na_values="\\N")
```

Comment: Thank you I was looking everywhere in the docs and couldn't find this!